# How to wrap to NativeArray in Nashorn without using classes from "internal" subpackage

Tags: java, nashorn

I have a Java array, say, `Object[]`, which I need to pass to the JS execution environment, which is `ScriptEngine`.

I cannot simply put it as a property in the following way:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
Object[] array = {1, 2, 3};
engine.put("prop", array);
```

because in the JS environment expression `Array.isArray(prop)` will be evaluated to `false`, whereas I need it to be `true`.

`jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeArray` constructors are closed, which means you cannot instantiate `NativeArray` explicitly.

One can, however, use `jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.instance().wrapAsObject` to convert Java array `Object[]` to `NativeArray`, and the resultant object would be recognized as a JS array, i.e. `Array.isArray` would return true for this object.

Although this gives the desired result, using classes from `internal` package is not a very good idea, and even worse idea if you are using Java 9.

Thus, I am wondering, is there a better way to provide Java object to the JS execution environment assuming I cannot change the JS source so that the object is recognized a true JS array, i.e. `Array.isArray` returns true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a native array through javascript, and then convert the corresponding `ScriptObjectMirror` to a `List<Object>`, it looks like the list will use the native array as underlying storage:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");     
ScriptObjectMirror jsArray = (ScriptObjectMirror) engine.eval("var arr = []; arr");

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Object> ls = jsArray.to(List.class);
ls.add(1);
ls.add(2);
ls.add(3);

System.out.println(ls); // [1, 2, 3]
engine.eval("print(arr)"); // 1,2,3
engine.eval("print(Array.isArray(arr))"); // true
```

You can then use this list on the Java side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, indeed, this is the possibility I forgot to mention in the question, but it looks like a workaround and it's a pity if there is no better way. I have upvoted your answer for now. Will accept the answer if there are no better alternatives.

Comment: I've accepted this answer, but I am still disappointed that there seems to be no beautiful way of creating a native array from Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Nashorn has a non-standard top-level `Java` object with – among other things – useful conversion methods named `to` and `from`. If you have a Java array `arr`, then `Java.from(arr)` will create a JS array as a shallow copy of the Java array. It also works with any `java.util.Collection`.

Note that in most cases, you can use Java arrays and lists natively in Nashorn; in cases where for some reason you need to have an actual JavaScript native array (e.g. to work with the array comprehensions functions), you will want to use this method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I assume you mean `Java` object in the JS execution environment. As I've stated in the question, I cannot modify the JavaScript I have to evaluate. Of course I can first define some variable and then evaluate `Java.from(javaArr)` for that variable, but again this requires interaction with `ScriptEngine`. Do you know a way to do it in plain Java code? It was possible with Rhino.

Answer (score 0):

Global.wrapAsObject()

```
/**
 * Wrap a Java object as corresponding script object
 *
 * @param obj object to wrap
 * @return    wrapped object
 */
public Object wrapAsObject(final Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
        return new NativeBoolean((Boolean)obj, this);
    } else if (obj instanceof Number) {
        return new NativeNumber(((Number)obj).doubleValue(), this);
    } else if (isString(obj)) {
        return new NativeString((CharSequence)obj, this);
    } else if (obj instanceof Object[]) { // extension
        return new NativeArray(ArrayData.allocate((Object[])obj), this);
    } else if (obj instanceof double[]) { // extension
        return new NativeArray(ArrayData.allocate((double[])obj), this);
    } else if (obj instanceof int[]) {
        return new NativeArray(ArrayData.allocate((int[]) obj), this);
    } else if (obj instanceof ArrayData) {
        return new NativeArray((ArrayData) obj, this);
    } else if (obj instanceof Symbol) {
        return new NativeSymbol((Symbol) obj, this);
    } else {
        // FIXME: more special cases? Map? List?
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).